# Set strict value for a field in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

I want to set strict value for a field in mongoose, for example in bellow schema

```
var Option_Sets = new Schema({
    setId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        dropDups: true,
        index: true
    },
    setName: { type: String },
    scope: String,
    components: [Schema.Types.Mixed]
});
```

I want to set the scope field just only can takes one in scope array

```
var scopes = ["Global", "Store View", "Website"];
```

Could someone help me a example and guiding me how to do it pleas.
Best thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform this try enum:

```
var Option_Sets = new Schema({
    setId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        dropDups: true,
        index: true
    },
    setName: { type: String },
    scope: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Global", "Store View", "Website"]
    },
    components: [Schema.Types.Mixed]
});
```

Comment: Thank to much..@B, Siscanu